# Check if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the following code not work?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZZe5X/18/

```
$('.submit').submit(function () {
    e.preventDefault()
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
        alert('ok')
    } else {
        alert('no')
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't see in your example any `.submit` class and a submit input. check this http://jsfiddle.net/ZZe5X/32/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZe5X/16/

Answer (score 1):

Okey:

1. you are missing the event:
   `$('.submit').submit(function () {` should be `$('.submit').submit(function (e) {`
2. The button is missing a type="submit" and it should be inside the form element.
3. The Form element is missing the class `submit`

this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/voigtan/ZZe5X/26/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a submit button in a form with the class `submit`, so your submit event handler never executes. Add `class="submit"` to your form tag and change `<button>Click me</button>` to `<input type="submit" value="Click me" />` and move it to before your `</form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
   $('.submit').submit(function () {

        if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
            alert('ok');
        } else {
            alert('no');
        }
      return false;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't have a submit class
2. You had .submit() set on a button, it needs to be .click
3. You weren't iterating through each checked box, which is what I assume you wanted to be doing.

See the tweaked example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZZe5X/33/